Why does the VScode do not recognize the wget in Windows？
I have downloaded and installed wget and configured environment variables：
GNU_HONE=E:\1-The knit of software\wget grab\GnuWin32
Path also include the '%GNU_HOME%\bin'
Why did I can't grab data from other website in VScode?
When I enter:
wget -r -np -nH --cut-dirs=2 -R "index.html*" "https://jyywiki.cn/os-demos/introduction/minimal/"

The VScode show that:
wget: The term 'wget' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

The instruction is correct because it come from an online course.
I also try to download the Openssl and deploy the environment variable but it still do not work.
By the way,I don't know how the terminal work in Vscode.
It seems that the instruction in Linux do not work in Vscode.

You did not show where you entered the command, but from the error message, I would guess that this is in a Windows Powershell. In this case, replace the terminal tag by a powershell tag.  Aside from this, the error message tells you what to do. Did you you follow it? Most likely your PATH is incorrect. BTW, the use of vscode is IMO irrelevant to this problem, but for the safe side, try it from a Windows console terminal.
